# How to print all property values of an object without naming the properties explicitly

Tags: c#, .net

How do I iterate through the `List<Galaxy>` and print out the value(s) of every property without having to write the property name(s) explicitly?

For example, I use this code to write property values of all properties of `galaxy`

```
private static void IterateThroughList()
{
    var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>
    {
        new Galaxy() { Name = "Tadpole", MegaLightYears = 400},
        new Galaxy() { Name = "Pinwheel", MegaLightYears = 25}
    };

    foreach (Galaxy theGalaxy in theGalaxies) 
    {
        // this part is of concern
        Console.WriteLine(theGalaxy.Name + "  " + theGalaxy.MegaLightYears);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid the explicit property names in this line

```
Console.WriteLine(theGalaxy.Name + "  " + theGalaxy.MegaLightYears);
```

So that, if my `Galaxy` class had more properties than `Name` and `MegaLightYears`, it would automatically print them too.

Comment: what does `Galaxy` look like.. could you show us..

Comment: You don't want to call out `Name` specifically? What do you mean?

Comment: I do not understand your question at all. What do you mean by "call out each element name"? Are you asking how to write a foreach loop while somehow eliding the declaration of the loop variable (here, `Galaxy theGalaxy`)?

Comment: So I'm not the only one who didn't understand the question!

Comment: I think that he asks how to iterate through the list and print the value of every property that each object contains without having to write them explicitly.

Comment: Yea @Dalmas that's what i meant let me try to rephrase sorry for the confusion, I couldn't put the words together in my head.

Comment: @Sewder, Joey's answer will do what you want, if you can update your `Galaxy` class.  If you can't, and you want this to magically work at runtime, you need to use reflection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to

- Write all properties without naming them
- Use it for any `Type` in a generic way

You can write a quick `Reflection` utility like this

```
public static string GetAllProperties(object obj)
{
    return string.Join(" ", obj.GetType()
                                .GetProperties()
                                .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(obj)));
}
```

And use it like

```
foreach (Galaxy theGalaxy in theGalaxies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetAllProperties(theGalaxy));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you want to avoid having to write the individual properties of the galaxy within the loop?

In that case you might overload `ToString` on `Galaxy` appropriately:

```
class Galaxy {
  public override string ToString() {
    return Name + "  " + MegaLightYearsl;
  }
}
```

Then you can just do

```
foreach (var galaxy in theGalaxies) {
  Console.WriteLine(galaxy);
}
```

However, since you only have one `ToString` to override, you cannot do this for wildly differing string representations of your object that may be needed in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I assume you're asking for how you iterate through a list by index instead of as a `foreach` loop.

Try a standard `for` loop, like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < theGalaxies.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(theGalaxies[i].Name + "  " + theGalaxies[i].MegaLightYears);
}
```